# Tomcat 6/7 JNDI with multiple datasources

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, tomcat, ejb, jndi

When there are more than one `<Resource>` elements in context.xml and more than one `<resource-ref>` elements in web.xml, my application begins to throw

```
TNS:no appropriate service handler found
```

and

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

However, if there is only one of the data sources in JNDI, meaning the other one use regular JDBC data source, the application runs like a charm

Both data sources come from same db URL but use different schema.

My guess is that it may be caused by the same database URL of each resources with different username/password(schema). But tomcat should be capable of handling such situation, so my reasoning is that there maybe some configuration I missed?

Another interesting finding is:
When I use jdbc url `jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:orcl` with SQL Developer to setup a connection, sometimes it connects without issue, but sometimes it gets rejected with the same issue: `appropriate service handler found` while this web application is active at the same time. However, the same JDBC URL works fine with another Spring application with regular JDBC connection(not JNDI). So what is the trick?

Here are the details of current config:

In Context.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/app_A" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:orcl"
    username="usernameA" password="passwordA" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" />
<Resource name="jdbc/app_B" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:orcl"
    username="usernameB" password="usernameB" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" />
```

In Web.xml of the application:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>Oracle Datasource for app_A</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/app_A</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
<resource-ref>
    <description>Oracle Datasource for app_B</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/app_B</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

In ApplicationContext.xml

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource1" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/app_A" resource-ref="true" />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource2" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/app_B" resource-ref="true" />
```

And finally I get exception piled up like this:

```
Jan 31, 2013 3:36:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Jan 31, 2013 3:36:56 PM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:412)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:699)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:631)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:485)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:539)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:237)
at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1061)
at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:671)
at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:270)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1100)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1618)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:385)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1042)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:301)
... 38 more
Jan 31, 2013 3:36:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Listener refused the  connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

Jan 31, 2013 3:36:56 PM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
```

Really not sure why the `no appropriate service handler found` error pops up, it seems the connection is not accepted/understood by orcl Listener.

Here is what I insert into persisntence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit1">
....
<jta-data-source>jdbc/app_A</jta-data-source>
....
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit2">
....
<jta-data-source>jdbc/app_B</jta-data-source>
....
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Works for me. I have about nine. Is it always the same resource that fails? And is that one maybe the one you remove when you test it with just one resource? So maybe there's something wrong with its resource definition?

Comment: @EJP Thank you. Turns out one of the jndi data source get password is incorrect. But after fixing that, the 'no appropriate service handler found' is still show up even though the application seems to work after that. Could you please give a hint on that? Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found` error might be the result of using an old-style JDBC connection string. According to chapter 8 [Data Sources and URLs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm#BEIJFHHB) of Oracle 11.1 JDBC Developer's Guide and Reference, connection string format is following:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host_name:port_number/service_name
```

There's also a note saying *"Starting Oracle Database 10g, Oracle Service IDs are not supported".* So the syntax you're using must have been suitable for Oracle 9i. It might work on newer versions, but that's not guaranteed.

So consider changing the format of your JDBC connection strings to follow the format suggested in the guide.

Also, for Oracle 9i onwards you should use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` rather than `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` as Oracle have stated that `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` is deprecated and support for this driver class will be discontinued.