# Accessing JNDI datasource defined in Web/App Server from Spring applicationContext xml / Junit Test cases

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7, datasource, jndi

Found couple of blogs providing steps to define jndi datasources and then accessing from Spring Container.

Method 1 :

```
1. Creating a file context.xml in src\main\webapp\META-INF folder and defining all 
   relevant jndi datasources.
2. Accessing jndi datasource from spring application context.xml file by using
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">        
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDB"/>
   </bean>
```

I tried above configuration and this works.

I found some other approaches too.

Method 2 : http://makecodeeasy.blogspot.in/2013/05/jndi-datasource-in-spring.html and [Tomcat 6/7 JNDI with multiple datasources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655825/tomcat-6-7-jndi-with-multiple-datasources) where

```
1. Datasources are defined in server.xml file (tomcat) and refered in web.xml file.
2. Accessing jndi datasources from spring application context.xml file 
   using JndiObjectFactoryBean with an additional resource ref attribute.
```

Again. what about using below line to achieve Step 2 in above two methods.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDB" />
```

Basically I want to know which one is better server connection pooling mechanism. Is there any advantage of one approach over other. Which one is advanced and why?

==EDITED==

Once spring application context gets datasource related info through jndi defined in context.xml, **how do Junit testcases which run Standalone not in Web Container would access JNDI resources ?**

Can someone help me in figuring out these.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html) documentation, it seems that both methods do exactly the same thing.

As far as connection pooling is concerned, JNDI lookups have nothing to do with that. Whatever connection pool you declare in `context.xml` (or whatever equivalent you use) will be looked up and used by Spring. If you declare [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/) as your connection pool then that will be used, likewise if you use the [Tomcat Connection pool](https://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html) or whatever else.

Comment: What about the way JNDI is used in spring context xml ? Use of JndiObjectFactoryBean or <jee:jndi-lookup/> both have same significance?

Comment: It seems to have the exact same meaning

Comment: How do Test cases run as context.xml in META-INF folder wont be available to Test Class.

Comment: Doing something like `@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/META-INF/spring/context.xml")` in the Test does work